# tree-structure cursor API

Tags: java, api, guava

I'm rewriting a cursor-API for tree-structures at the moment. I have methods like:

```
/**
 * Move cursor to parent node of currently selected node.
 * 
 * @return the cursor instance
 */
INodeCursor moveToParent();

/**
 * Move cursor to first child node of currently selected node.
 * 
 * @return the cursor instance
 */
INodeCursor moveToFirstChild();
```

and corresponding boolean hasParent() and hasFirstChild()... methods. Until now the moveToX()-methods also returned a boolean value, but I think things like:

`trx.moveToParent().moveToParent().insertFirstChild(...).moveToRightSibling()`... are much more interesting if you know what you do. However I'm not sure what to do if it fails (return null to produce an immediate NPE?). Maybe it's best to return the cursor instance and the caller must be aware that the cursor might not have been moved at all.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Edit: Maybe this is also a use case for Google Guava Optional? This way I've got the best from both?

`trx.moveToRightSibling().get().moveToRightSibling().get().insertTextAsFirstChild("foo")`

and

`if (trx.moveToRightSibling.isPresent()) && trx.moveToRightSibling.isPresent() && "foo".equals(rtx.getValue) { ... }`

plus additional trx.hasRightSibling()... methods. So maybe a self-written simple wrapper with about the same semantics but different names.

`if (trx.moveToRightSibling().didSucceed() && ...)` and 
`trx.moveToRightSibling().get().moveToRightSibling().get() ...)`

Edit 2: For instance:

```
/**
 * Determines if the {@link INodeCursor} moved to a node or not. Based on the
 * idea of providing a wrapper just like in Google Guava's {@link Optional}
 * class.
 * 
 * @author Johannes Lichtenberger
 * 
 * @param <T>
 *          type parameter, the cursor
 */
public abstract class Move<T extends INodeCursor> {
  /**
   * Returns a {@link Moved} instance with no contained reference.
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static <T extends INodeCursor> Move<T> notMoved() {
    return (Move<T>) NotMoved.INSTANCE;
  }

  /**
   * Returns a {@code Moved} instance containing the given non-null reference.
   */
  public static <T extends INodeCursor> Moved<T> moved(final @Nonnull T pMoved) {
    return new Moved<T>(checkNotNull(pMoved));
  }

  /**
   * Determines if the cursor has moved.
   * 
   * @return {@code true} if it has moved, {@code false} otherwise
   */
  public abstract boolean hasMoved();

  /**
   * Get the cursor reference.
   * 
   * @return cursor reference
   */
  public abstract T get();
}
```

Edit 3: and my moveTo(long)-method where all other moveToX()-methods are based on:

```
@Override
public Move<? extends INodeCursor> moveTo(final long pNodeKey) {
    assertNotClosed();
    if (pNodeKey == EFixed.NULL_NODE_KEY.getStandardProperty()) {
        return Move.notMoved();
    }

    // Remember old node and fetch new one.
    final INode oldNode = mCurrentNode;
    Optional<? extends INodeBase> newNode;
    try {
        // Immediately return node from item list if node key negative.
        if (pNodeKey < 0) {
            if (mItemList.size() > 0) {
                newNode = mItemList.getItem(pNodeKey);
            } else {
                newNode = Optional.absent();
            }
        } else {
            final Optional<? extends INodeBase> node = mPageReadTrx.getNode(
                    pNodeKey, EPage.NODEPAGE);
            newNode = node;
        }
    } catch (final SirixIOException e) {
        newNode = Optional.absent();
    }

    if (newNode.isPresent()) {
        mCurrentNode = (INode) newNode.get();
        return Move.moved(this);
    } else {
        mCurrentNode = oldNode;
        return Move.notMoved();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no way a bunch of random people on SO can tell you how your application should behave in the event of an error!

Comment: It's a general API question. What would you expect? Would you even return the cursor instance or a boolean value?

Comment: Either one works, and either one needs error checking - if you return booleans, just have to check the result before calling the next one. For me returning instances (which may trigger a NPE) is easier to use.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently not sure if I should really trigger the NPE or just not move the cursor and the caller must check if the selected node has really changed or not (if he is not sure that the for instance in this case the parent of the parent may not exist). But I think the NPE would also be appropriate, as other tree-structure APIs usually return the nodes (and null in case the node doesn't exist).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments above:

Question boils down to:
1) Should I use boolean returns or instances

Either way requires error checking:

```
if (trx.moveToParent()) {
    if (trx.moveToParent()) {
        trx.doSomething();
```

vs

```
try {
    trx.moveToParent().moveToParent().doSomething();
}
catch(NPE ex) {
```

The first way is slightly more obvious that trx is being modified, but it is a bit more inconvenient to use (e.g. error reporting needs an `else` for each conditional [set a flag and then do a single error report based on the flag])

The idea of not changing the node is the same as returning a boolean, but even uglier

```
trx.noveToParent();
if (trx.didMove()) {
    trx.moveToParent();
    if (trx.didMove()) {
        trx.doSomething();
```

If it was me I'd return the node and throw NPEs - you do need to ensure that your variable is updated correctly. i.e. trx.moveToParent().moveToParent() actually modifies trx twice rather than once change to trx and one to some anonymous copy. Good unit tests will help here.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, in situations like this, i would create your own exception:

```
public class NoSuchNodeException extends RuntimeException {
  ...
}
```

This exception would be thrown from your cursor methods.  It allows the client to respond to a meaningful condition (they've requested moving to a node that doesn't exist), rather than a generic NPE, which could mean anything.  Whether the exception is checked or not depends on your requirements.  I find unchecked exceptions to be much friendlier in this case though.

```
public INodeCursor moveToParent() {
   if (currentNode.parent == null) {
       throw new NoSuchNodeException("Node has no parent", currentNode);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hm, but consider the following: `if (trx.hasRightSibling() && trx.moveToRightSibling() && "foo".equals(trx.getValue())) { ... }`. Even the method which returns null is uglier in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can be clever and create a NullNode instance. When you moveToChild and there is no child, return a NullNode and set it's parent to your actual node. Then, you can check isNullNode if you get an empty one, and you can walk it back to where you fell off the tree with a "printPath" method or something.

If the assumption is that your branches are normally correct, it makes your method chaining much cleaner since ideally they rarely fail.

Comment: Isn't it like proposed in my edit? I have edited once more to provide a short snipped how my moveTo(long) method looks like (where all other methods are based on).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to throw an own exception (maybe a subclass of NPE) immediately, so it's fail-fast. Sometimes you may want to make things easier via something a method `lenient()` returning a different class having all the moving methods, but no mutating methods. The moving methods of the lenient class never throws; in case of an error they return a failed instance. By using `strict()` you get back to the original class or get an exception in case there was an error somewhere on the path.

Normally, you'd do something like

```
trx.up().right().right().firstChild().addChild(....);
```

and get an exception as soon as a problem occur (yes, I'd simplify the method names, how is "moveToRight" any better than "right"?). The use of "lenient" could be like

```
ILenientNodeCursor c1 = trx.lenient().up().right().right().firstChild();
if (c1.failed()) c1 = trx.right().right().firstChild();
if (!c1.failed()) c1.strict().addChild(...);
```

I'm not very sure about "lenient", but I'm pretty sure that the normal behavior should be strict, throwing as fast as possible. This is surely much less error-prone than anything else and most of the time easier to use.

Comment: What do you think about checking the postcondition as suggested in my edits? Or like another Will Hartung said, a NullNode, which is already existing  (a wrapper to determine if it's a "structural node", or not). I have already changed the API, but have to debug, because somehow something doesn't work anymore (most unit tests fail ;-)). However I don't think it's too much of a burden to use `trx.up().get().right().get().right().get()`, but ok, it seems a bit ugly. Maybe your approach is better. What do others think?

Comment: As for the NullNode, it could be done as implementation for the lenient part, but I'd strongly prefer to throw on each problem by default. I wouldn't use `Optional`, as I can't see any case here when it brings any advantage. In your above chain you had to write `get()` three times -- that would be acceptable but only if you could write something meaningful without those many "gets". Can you?

Comment: @Johannes: Nearly everything can be done with lenient, e.g. `trx.lenient().right().lastNonFailed()` moves to the right if possible, but again, I'm pretty sure that what's needed most of time is the strict fail-fast behavior. Lenient just allows you to have both.

Comment: Actually I think it's more a question of that I really need both cases (boolean return value and the transaction instance, not so much about fail fast or not). Otherwise I can't use moveToX()-methods in loops and other statements.

Comment: For instance to traverse all ancestors and do something: `do { trx.acceptVisitor(Visitor.getInstance()); } while (trx.moveToParent())`. Well, this can be done with `hasParent()` and `moveToParent()` but hm. I have got less usecases for the chained move-methods. Usually only get the right sibl. of the right sibl. and then proceed with some conditional statements.

Comment: The alternative you described doesn't look that bad: `for (; trx.hasParent(); trx.up()) trx.acceptVisitor(v);`. That's a classical loop, a bit longer than yours but easier to read. Ehhh... it's actually wrong, as it fails to make the last iteration. Here the lenient variant could help. Or something crazy like `for (INodeCursor trx1 : trx.iterable(UP)) trx1.acceptVisitor(v);`

Comment: why crazy? ;-) The axis have been implemented some time ago, but still a bit  strange in my opinion as the return values are almost useless (the unique node-key of the node the cursor moved to). Then it's more like for (final IAxis axis = new AncestorAxis(trx); axis.hasNext();) { axis.next(); axis.getTrx().acceptVisitor(); } I agree, it would make more sense to return the trx-cursor instance, wich would eliminate the getTrx() method. But luckily all axis (for instance XPath axis and a few more) inherit from an abstract class. However, you know which instance you provided.